# If I have nested async/await calls should I be concerned with accumulated overhead?

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I'm processing data via a number of channels where each channel feeds into the next (pipeline processing). I end up with a `spawn` at the top that looks like this:

```rust
let future = async move {
    while let Ok(msg) = r.recv().await {
        forwarder.receive(msg).await;
    }
};
executor_pool::ExecutorPool::spawn(future).detach();
```

The `Forwarder` looks like this:

```
Forwarder {
    pub fn validate_sequence(&mut self, msg: TestMessage) -> Result<TestMessage, TestMessage>
    pub async fn handle_action(&mut self, cmd: TestMessage);
    pub async fn handle_notification(&mut self);
    pub async fn receive(&mut self, cmd: TestMessage) {
        match self.handle_config(cmd) {
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(msg) => match self.validate_sequence(msg) {
                Ok(msg) => {
                    self.handle_action(msg).await;
                    self.handle_notification().await;
                },
                Err(msg) => panic!("{} sequence error: expecting {} not cmd {:#?}", self.header(), self.next_seq, msg),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Both `handle_action` and `handle_notification` call into a sender which is another `async fn`. My concern is two-fold. The entire pathway to the send (or any other `async fn`) seems to require an async/await wrapper. In my case I'm 3 deep at the send. Which seems to be a bit ugly, particularly if I have to do any refactoring. Second, is there a runtime cost for each level of async/await or is the compiler smart enough to collapse these? If it helps to make this more concrete, think of it as audio processing where the first stage decodes, the next does leveling, the next does mixing, and then the final does encoding.

To expand of the refactoring concern, let's look at refactoring a for loop.

```
pub async fn handle_action(&mut self, cmd: FwdMessage) {
  match cmd {
    FwdMessage::TestData(_) => {
      for sender in &self.senders {
        for _ in 0 .. self.forwarding_multiplier {                       
          sender.send(FwdMessage::TestData(self.send_count)).await.ok();
          self.send_count += 1;
        }
      }
    },
    _ => panic!("unhandled action"),
  }
}
```

Rather than a `for` loop, we'd like to use an `iterator`. However, that's going to require an async closure -- which is something I haven't figured out how to even express.

Comment: *"Which seems to be a bit ugly"* - can you clarify what hinders refactoring? Are you just talking about each function needing to be `async` when calling other `async` functions?

Comment: Yes. Having to add async through the call path could result in having async and non-async methods which are nearly identical. I'm left wondering if there shouldn't be a way to elude async/await based upon the return argument of a call.

Answer (score 1):

Just the act of nesting `async` functions does not introduce any overhead.

The `async`/`await` syntax compiles to a `Future` that is basically a state-machine that can execute your code in a way that it can be suspended when it needs to wait for something and resumed later. An `async` function and all (statically known) `await`'d futures are compiled together into the same `Future`; the function boundaries somewhat melt away. So yes, the compiler is "smart enough to collapse these" together.